# C# .NET Call scanner Manager and show the picture

Tags: c#, .net

Create an application that manages to scan documents through WIA and displays them in a picturebox. But it does it directly.

What I want is that when I press the scan button the wizard (Scanner Settings) will open by default to be able to see the preview and other options, then when I scan if it shows me the result in the picturebox.

Some help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Only when you use a sdk of your device can you do that.
Scanning purpose you will need to use TWAIN SDK/Wrapper for .Net.

[example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner)

```
class Twain
{
    Init();
    Select();
    Acquire();
    PassMessage();
    TransferPictures();
}
```

Comment: Hi!, Whit WIA i can scann and show the picture on a picturebox, but the wizard dont show hmmm